# Ubuntu 22.04 drops to busybox on a Lenovo ideapad laptop

Tags: boot, kernel, kubuntu, nvme, 22.04

After updating from Kubuntu 21.10 to Kubuntu 22.04, boot drops to a (initramfs) prompt/busybox. When I type "exit" I get the "Gave up waiting for root file system device" error message and "ALERT! UUID=[nvme drive UUID] does not exist. Dropping to a shell!"

I can still boot into KDE when selecting the older kernel version 5.13.0-40-lowlatency. I have tried the newer kernel versions 5.15.025-generic, 5.15.0.24-lowlatency, 5.17.4-051421-generic and 5.14.21-051421-lowlatency and all have produced the same problem. When removing the the "pci=nocrs" kernel paramater in Grub for these newer versions, the system boots into KDE but the touchpad does not work. Kernel version 5.13.0-40-lowlatency works without removing the "pci=nocrs" parameter.

My hardware is a Lenovo ideapad lenovo ideapad 3 15IIL05, Processors: 8 × Intel Core i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz, Memory: 7,3 GiB of RAM, Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel Iris Plus Graphics. I have upgraded the hard drive that came with the machine to a Kingston SA2000M8500G 465,8GiB nvme drive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your new initramfs does not include the necessary drivers for your new nvme storage?

If you boot a 22.04 Rescue System, can you see the nvme there? This would be the perfect place to find out what module is responsible for that device, and insert it into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.

I've just tracked down a similar issue where `dmraid` (dm_mirror) wasn't included in the ramdisk anymore. (and on top, it also didnt partprobe the device when the driver was included...)